# C read and store string

Tags: c, string, exit

I want to read two strings using scanf and at same time check if the first given word is 'quit'

Example:

Enter origin and destination (quit to exit): Node1 Node4

Node1 and Node4 are connected

Enter origin and destination (quit to exit): quit

Then it quits..

I'm using this, but I have to input two strings before it checks if the first one is == quit, so the program quits.

```
printf("Enter origin and destination (quit to exit): ");
scanf("%s %s", startStopNodes[0], startStopNodes[1]);

if (strcmp(startStopNodes[0], "quit") == 0) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: Just use two seperate `scanf` calls. Or a single `fgets` to get the whole line and `sscanf` or `strtok` to extract the tokens.

Comment: @kaylum I have to read all the line at the same time. So I guess I have to use fgets with a buffer. How do you use sscanf to extract the strings to each variable though?

Comment: Why do you have to read the line at the same time? The user sees no differenence if you use two `scanf` calls to read one word at a time. If you want to use `sscanf` please read the man page or do a search (there are countless examples).

Comment: It's a specification rule. I'm working on an assignment. Anyway, managed to get it to work. Thanks for your help! :)